# sass/sprockets: Generating 2 stylesheets that differ only in a few values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

I'm working on a Rails project with quite some stylesheets written in sass. The layout is as follows right now:

We have a manifest (application.sass) that requires a couple of other sass files:

```
// in application.sass:
/*
 *= require reset
 *= require base
 *= require forms
 ...
 */
```

These other stylesheets all include a "partial" with some color definitions and use these extensively:

```
// in _colors.sass:
$foreground: '#F00'
$background: '#0F0'
// ...


// in base.sass:
@import colors.sass
#content
  background-color: $background
// ...


// in forms.sass:
@import colors.sass
form
  color: $foreground
// ...
```

I'd now like to generate a copy of the resulting stylesheet that contains the same rules with just the color definitions swapped out (e.g. a red_application.sass that is an exact clone of application.sass with just all color definitions in _var.sass swapped out).

I tried moving the importing of the color definitions into the manifest file like follows:

```
// in application.sass:
/*
 *= require _colors.sass
 *= require reset
 *= require base
 *= require forms
 ...
 */

// in red_application.sass:
/*
 *= require _red_colors.sass
 *= require reset
 *= require base
 *= require forms
 ...
 */

// in base.sass:
// no @import
#content
  background-color: $background
// ...


// in forms.sass:
// no @import
form
  color: $foreground
// ...
```

Unfortunately, this does not work since the single stylesheets (base.sass, forms.sass) cannot be generated without the @import statement since they do not know about the variables used within them.

How could I restructure our stylesheets to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix sprockets requires with scss imports.

For sprocket to work, each required file must be a complete css (after compilation), and the resulting file will contain the contents of all css files.

`scss` imports are resolved during the compilation phase, so you can't do as you intend.

What you can do is to import the colors in each of the main scss, and don't let sprockets require things:

in `application.sass`:

```
@import _colors
@import reset
@import base
@import forms
```

in `red_application.sass`:

```
@import _red_colors
@import reset
@import base
@import forms
```

Comment: I already came up with this solution as well... The not so nice thing about it is that you can no longer enable sprocket-debug-mode (a.k.a. having each sub-stylesheet loaded via a separate link tag so that you find errors easier). But I guess this is not possible, since "For sprocket to work, each required file must be a complete css (after compilation)"...

Comment: Exactly. Either you use scss imports, or you do separate CSS with sprockets debug. If it wasn't the case, it would mean that a browser could use variables among stylesheets, and that's exactly the point of inventing SCSS and compiling into CSS (so at least during development you can use variables...)

Comment: I mean, css does not support variables, and browsers only support css. Sprockets compilation transforms SCSS in valid CSS, including includes and resolving variables. Even if you skip sprockets compression, you need sprockets compilation (for coffeescript too!) for the browser to understand it!